# HTML how to align two tables in one row?

Tags: html, html-table

How to align two tables in one row, in the middle of the page?
The results that I want to see:

```
                                11 12   11 12
                                21 22   21 22
```

The result that I get:

```
11 12
21 22
11 12
21 22
```

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this, adjust the width as per the requirement and if you want to place at the center of the document the take a div and align it center of the page and place the following html in it.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:50%;float:left">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td> 11</td>
  <td> 12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 21</td>
  <td> 22</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:50%;float:left">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td> 11</td>
  <td> 12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 21</td>
  <td> 22</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just add a <div style="width:100px; margin:0 auto;"> at the first of this and a </div> at the end and this one is simpler, change 100px as you wish

Answer (score 2):

You can create another table and embed these two tables in that :

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
          </tr>
    </table>    
 </td>
 <td>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

or you can use the float property in css .

Answer (score -1):

This http://jsfiddle.net/pNH3T/ is one possible solution:

```
<div style="display:block; width:100%">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width:200px;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left">
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```