# How to align (multiple) tables as centered (and responsively)?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I'm trying to align two (and later maybe more) tables horizontally.
I am also trying to do so as part of a template I am using from a CMS.

The aforementioned solutions at:

[HTML how to align two tables in one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278167/html-how-to-align-two-tables-in-one-row)
[HTML -- two tables side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690223/html-two-tables-side-by-side)

did not work for me.

Well, first of all, the "mixture" of div and table has been neglected on other posts (e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-place-two-tables-side-by-side/6499/5) as bad practice.

Moreover, when using

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}
```

it de facto means, ALL text (also in paragraphs) is displayed as centered. That's not what I want.

My code stems from a template for a CMS. Cocerning the tables, it looks like this by default:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.table {
    clear:both;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
    width:100%;*/
    font: 0.85em;
}
```

I then thought, I'll another two classes:

```
table.beirat_l, table.beirat_r,{
margin: 25px auto 25px auto;
display:inline-table;
float: left;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="beirat_l">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
    <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="beirat_r">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
    <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But they did not work either. In fact, nothing I am trying in this CSS has an effect on my two tables.

Also, another requirement is the tables need to be responsive, so they need to shift vertically when viewed on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

Put your table in a container and align that container side be side.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="beirat_l">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <table class="beirat_r">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" />
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

After that set container width 50% and float left.

```
.container{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <table class="beirat_l">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="beirat_r">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img alt="Dr. Heiko Breit" class="img-responsive" height="241" src="http://kloss.biz/media/pics/Dr.-Heiko-Breit.jpg" style="" width="254" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dr. Heiko Breit</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Wrap them in a flex container and if you want to wrap to avoid overlapping then you can use {flex-wrap:wrap}

Comment: Hmmm, thanx a lot. But as stated in my question, mixing div and table are considered not a good way to do so... but you are suggesting exactly that... so, I am not sure if I shall follow this...

Comment: Also: it does NOT solve my problem. The tables are still displayed aligned vertically.