# Aligning tables or DIV in one ROW using HTML Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in which I can't align the two table in `PREPARED BY:` and `CHARGE` It's not necessary to make two tables I tried just div the PREPARED BY: but it doesn't work so I came up to make another table one is belong to the PREPARED BY: with the name below and the other one is the charge table to below until Grand Total , the purpose why I created two tables because I loop the other table if I merge them into one the `PREPARED by` table will be loop two and I avoid that, I tried aligning them but it doesn't work,

**The result must be like this image**

[image]

**What I've tried**

```css
       
            .container-wrapper {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                height: auto;
                padding-bottom: 50px;
                background-color: #cccccc;
              }
             
              .container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5%;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                border-radius: 8px;
                box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                padding: 0 10px;
              }
             
              .print-button {
                background-color: #b2c2ce;
                color: white;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 8px 12px;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-right: 500px;
              }
             
              .container-body, .container-body2,.container-body3,.container-body4  {
                width: 210mm;
                height:auto;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 20px;
                position: relative;
                padding: 50px;
              }
              .appendix {
                position: absolute;
                top: 65px;
                right: 50px;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-style: italic;
              }
             
              table {
                border: 3px solid;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 40px;
              }
             
              th,
              td {
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
              }
             
              th {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
              }
             
              .center-text {
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: top;
              }
              .dvnumber {
                background-color:#c6e0b4;
                border:1.8px solid;
                font-size: 12px;
              }
              .align-u-left {
              text-align: left;
              vertical-align: top;
            }
             
              @media print {
                .container {
                  display: none;
                }
             
                .container-body, .container-body2,.container-body3,.container-body4{
                  background-color: #f0f0f0;
                  box-shadow: none;
                  width: 210mm;
                  height: 297mm;
                  margin-top: -30px;
                }
             
                .container h3 {
                  color: transparent;
                }
             
                .container-wrapper {
                  align-items: flex-start;
                }
             
                table {
                  margin-top: 15px;
                  border: 3px solid;
                }
             
                .appendix {
                  top: 45px;
                }
             
                /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
                .center-text b {
                  font-size: 14px;
                }
                .dvnumber {
                  background-color: #c6e0b4 !important; /* Use !important to ensure it's applied */
                  color: black; /* Make sure text remains readable */
                  border: 1.8px solid;
                  font-size: 10px;
                }
        
                .container-body2,.container-body3,.container-body4 {
                  page-break-before: always;
                }
              }
             .innerTable{
               margin:0px;
               border-color:white;  
             }
             .lastRow{
               padding:0px;
             }
        
             .align-text-right{
              text-align: right;
             }
             .align-text-right{
              text-align: right;
             }
             .no-border{
              border: 0;
             }
        
             .footer {
              margin-top: 95%;
              
            }
```

```html
   <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h3></h3>
            <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
          </div>

    <div class="container-body3">
        <span ><center>Test data test data tes est data test data tes TEST<br> Test / Test / Test<br> Test#  Test.0.dv_no  <br> for Date 8, 2023</center></span>
        <table >
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr >
              <td><b>CODE</b></td>
              <td><b>Account Number</b></td>
              <td><b>ID NUMBER</b></td>
              <td><b><center>NAME</center></b></td>
              <td><b>AMOUNT</b></td>
              <td><b>CHARGE</b></td>
              <td><b><center>PURPOSE</center></b></td>
            
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td class="align-text-right" style="padding: 2;">214214214</td>
              <td class="align-text-right" style="padding: 4;">4214124</td>
              <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;">214</td>
              <td  class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;">4124</td>
              <td style="padding: 4;"><center> testt </center></td>
              <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;"> emp.charges </td>
              <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;"> emp.purpose </td>
            </tr>

           
            <tr >
              <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"><center><b> 50000 </b></center></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;"><center><b> 1 </b></center></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>


                  
        <table style="border: 0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr >
              <td style="width: 50px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 125px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 100px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 140px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width:80px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width:72px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="border:0;"></td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 13px;padding: 0;" colspan="2" class="no-border">PREPARED BY:</td>
              
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="no-border"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="no-border"></td>
                <td class="no-border"><center><b><u>Lebron James</u></b></center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="no-border"></td>
                <td class="no-border"><center>AO II</center></td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table style="border: 0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr >
              <td style="width: 50px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 125px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 100px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width: 140px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width:80px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="width:72px;border:0;"></td>
              <td style="border:0;"></td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="no-border"></td>
              <td class="no-border" colspan="2"></td>
              <td style="font-size: 13px;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255); padding: 0;" class="no-border"><b>CHARGE</b></td>
              <td style="font-size: 13px;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255); padding: 0;" colspan="2" class="no-border"><b><center>Sum of AMOUNT</center></b></td>
            </tr>


              <tr >
                <td class="no-border"></td>
                <td class="no-border"></td>
                <td class="no-border"></td>
                <td style="padding: 0;" class="no-border"> 4214</td>
                <td style="padding: 0;"  class="no-border" colspan="2"><center> 4214214 </center></td>
            
              </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td class="no-border"></td>
              <td style="font-size: 13px;padding: 0;" class="no-border"><center><b></b></center></td>
              <td class="no-border"></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255);" class="no-border"><b>GRAND Total</b></td>
              <td style="padding: 0;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255);"  class="no-border" colspan="2"><center><b> 4214214 </b></center></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        
        <div class="footer">
          Cash Unit's Copy
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at what you are doing; you are first setting up width for each column by creating dummy `td`s with specified width, with last `td` to cover the remaining width (because `table` `width` is set to 100% so that it has to fill the width of parent). When you put `table { width: 100%}` each `table` will occupy 100% of parent width. So more than one table can't occupy  a row (unless you decide to put one above another using properties like `position: fixed` or `float`).

Comment: Please check this also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14278167/21598034 . But your code has other problems as well

Comment: Tables are not supposed to be used for layout purposes. If you want things align use a CSS grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make two tables appear on same row, I suggest this method: Put those tables on a bigger table. But as I have mentioned in the comments you are using dummy `td`s for defining the width of a column. So I have removed unnecessary `td`s present on the first row.

```css
.container-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.print-button {
  background-color: #b2c2ce;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 500px;
}

.container-body,
.container-body2,
.container-body3,
.container-body4 {
  width: 210mm;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}

.appendix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}

table {
  border: 3px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.dvnumber {
  background-color: #c6e0b4;
  border: 1.8px solid;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.align-u-left {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table.myClass * { /*new*/
  border: 0;
}

table table tr { /*new*/
  height: 30px;
}

@media print {
  .container {
    display: none;
  }
  .container-body,
  .container-body2,
  .container-body3,
  .container-body4 {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
  .container h3 {
    color: transparent;
  }
  .container-wrapper {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  table {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 3px solid;
  }
  .appendix {
    top: 45px;
  }
  /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
  .center-text b {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .dvnumber {
    background-color: #c6e0b4 !important;
    /* Use !important to ensure it's applied */
    color: black;
    /* Make sure text remains readable */
    border: 1.8px solid;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .container-body2,
  .container-body3,
  .container-body4 {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}

.innerTable {
  margin: 0px;
  border-color: white;
}

.lastRow {
  padding: 0px;
}

.align-text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.align-text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.no-border {
  border: 0;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h3></h3>
    <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container-body3">
    <span><center>Test data test data tes est data test data tes TEST<br> Test / Test / Test<br> Test#  Test.0.dv_no  <br> for Date 8, 2023</center></span>
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>CODE</b></td>
          <td><b>Account Number</b></td>
          <td><b>ID NUMBER</b></td>
          <td><b><center>NAME</center></b></td>
          <td><b>AMOUNT</b></td>
          <td><b>CHARGE</b></td>
          <td><b><center>PURPOSE</center></b></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td class="align-text-right" style="padding: 2;">214214214</td>
          <td class="align-text-right" style="padding: 4;">4214124</td>
          <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;">214</td>
          <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;">4124</td>
          <td style="padding: 4;">
            <center> testt </center>
          </td>
          <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;"> emp.charges </td>
          <td class="align-text-left" style="padding: 4;"> emp.purpose </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
          <td style="padding: 0;"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
          <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
          <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
          <td style="padding: 0;">
            <center><b> 50000 </b></center>
          </td>
          <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
          <td style="padding: 0;">
            <center><b> 1 </b></center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


    <table style="border: 0;" class="myClass" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table style="border: 0;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50px;border:0;"></td>
                  <td style="width: 125px;border:0;"></td>
                  <td style="width: 100px;border:0;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size: 13px;padding: 0;" colspan="2" class="no-border">PREPARED BY:</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="no-border"></td>
                  <td class="no-border">
                    <center><b><u>Lebron James</u></b></center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="no-border"></td>
                  <td class="no-border">
                    <center>AO II</center>
                  </td>
                </tr>


              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table style="border: 0;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 140px;border:0;"></td>
                  <td style="width:80px;border:0;"></td>
                  <td style="width:72px;border:0;"></td>
                  <td style="border:0;"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size: 13px;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255); padding: 0;" class="no-border"><b>CHARGE</b></td>
                  <td style="font-size: 13px;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255); padding: 0;" colspan="2" class="no-border"><b><center>Sum of AMOUNT</center></b></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0;" class="no-border"> 4214</td>
                  <td style="padding: 0;" class="no-border" colspan="2">
                    <center> 4214214 </center>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0;;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255);" class="no-border"><b>GRAND Total</b></td>
                  <td style="padding: 0;background-color:rgb(158, 198, 255);" class="no-border" colspan="2">
                    <center><b> 4214214 </b></center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="footer">
      Cash Unit's Copy
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

I have tried to keep your original code as much as possible, but I have removed extra cells which cause extra columns.

Comment: Just a little bit I tried to move a bit upward the `AO II`  or being align to the `GRAND Total` can you make that? I mean there's no space between `Lebron James` and AO II?

Comment: I have edited my answer. For aligning them I had to specify height of the `tr` on `table`s inside the bigger `table`.